# Sharing Variables between functions in ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm dabbling around with ES6 Syntax in Node.js. As a starting point I just tried creating a simple class that configures and returns an Express server - not sure if this would be good or not in production, though.

I'm having trouble with accessing the classes member variables in other functions. Take a look at the code below:

```
import express from 'express'
import http from 'http'

const _server = null
const _app = null

class HttpServer {

    constructor (port) {
        this._port = port;

        if (this._app === null) {
            this._app = express()
        }

        if (this._server === null) {
            this._server = http.createServer(this._app)
        }

        return this._server
    }

    start (callback) {

        this._server.listen(this._port, (error) => {
            return callback(error)
        })
    }

}

export default HttpServer
```

The constructor seems to be working okay, although when I call the `start` method I get an error that the variable `this._server` is `undefined`. I thought the `this` keyword would be able to access the variables. I have tried replacing the `this` accessing method to using `HttpServer._server` but with no luck. Any tips or advice would be appreciated!

If I've made silly mistakes, please forgive me, I haven't hopped on the ES6 train before this!

Comment: That's because you are checking if `this._app` is `null` - that will fail because it's not null, it's `undefined`, just like `this._server`. You never create an instance of `express`. Also, you don't need those checks in constructor, simply create `this._app = express()` and `this._server = http.createServer(this._app);`

Comment: Ah okay, that does make sense. How would I set them both to `null` like I tried to do with the `const globals`?

Comment: In constructor, you'd initialize them to `null` with `this._app = null;`.

Comment: I removed the null checks & in the `start` I logged `typeof` port, app and server.

I get `undefined`, `function` and `object`. The port is no longer being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is necessary to remove the check for null
2. There is no need to return anything from constructor

---

```
class HttpServer {

    constructor (port) {
        this._port = port
        this._app = express()
        this._server = http.createServer(this._app)
    }

    start (callback) {
        this._server.listen(this._port, (error) => {
            return callback(error)
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: It was my silly mistake, I've been working a lot with Singleton classes so it was merely habit. I removed all the null checking. I'm still getting an undefined error for this._port in the start function though.

Comment: @nickcorin And you create a server instance something like: `new HttpServer(3000)`?

Comment: Stupid me. I was trying to use the code like this:

`const server = new HttpServer(); server.start(8000);`

Thanks for the help. This was perfect.